# Navigate to street Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my android app, I have 4 variables: street, number, state and country.
Now I would like to show a marker on the exact place depending on the value of the variables.
I found out how I could navigate to certain latitudes and longitudes, but not to streetnames.
How can I navigate to a certain street a in state in a country with the Google Maps API?

Comment: You can convert your street address to long/lat and then navigate.. There is a method like toLatLong()... Check the api.. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the lat/long by using the Geocoder.  Here is a method I have used to attain the lat/long.

```
public static List<Address> getGeoLocation(String address, Context context){

    Geocoder go = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = go.getFromLocationName(address, 1);


    } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return addresses;
}
```